# JSON - access the field of a field

Tags: javascript, json

Let's say I have:

```
 A = {

       B: {
          key : "value1"
       },

       C: {
          key : "value2"
       }
       ..............
}
```

How can I get the values of the keys using a loop?

I tried something like:

```
for(ob in A)
{
    console.log(ob);
    console.log(ob.key);
}
```

but I get:

```
B
undefined
C
undefined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(var propName in A)
{
    console.log(A[propName].key);
}
```

popName s are B and C in this case. Code will log result of A["B"] and A["C"]

Answer (score 5):

`ob` holds the property name, not the value.

You want to log `A[ob]` and `A[ob].key`.